# Significado de frases del poema "La pobreza. El dinero." de Quevedo

Tags: significado, poesía

¿Alguien me puede explicar qué significan las siguientes frases del poema *La pobreza. El dinero.* de Quevedo?

> Pues amarga la verdad,
>   Quiero echarla de la boca;
>   Y si al alma su hiel toca,
>   Esconderla es necedad.
>   **Sépase, pues libertad**
>   **Ha engendrado en mi pereza**
>   ***La Pobreza.***

Y:

> ¿Quién los jueces con pasión,
>   Sin ser ungüento, hace humanos,
>   Pues untándolos las manos
>   Los ablanda el corazón?
>   **¿Quién gasta su opilación
>
>   Con oro y no con acero?
>
>   *El Dinero.***

Comment: Debes hacer does preguntas, una para cada frase.  También, en este sitio, es normal que al hacer una pregunta, cada persona explique la investigación que ya ha realizado.  Es decir, ¿qué piensas que signifique?  ¿qué parte te ha confundido?  Así podemos darte respuestas más adecuadas.

Comment: La primera creo que va así: hay una verdad incómoda que corresponde publicar: que la libertad junto a la pereza han hecho pobre al narrador.

Comment: [Opilación](http://dle.rae.es/?id=R6YV0KB) parece referirse a una obstrucción de flujo corporal (p.ej. un absceso) que _debe ser liberada_ (gastada) mediante una operación (_con acero_), y que se sana con más cuidado del estrictamente necesario (_con oro_)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En la primera frase

> Sépase, pues libertad / Ha engendrado en mi pereza / La Pobreza

se nota que hay un hipérbaton, o sea un "desorden" sintáctico intencional. Podría ordenarse así:

> Sépase, pues, [que] la pobreza ha engendrado libertad en mi pereza.

que yo interpreto así: "tengan en cuenta que la pobreza es la causa de que yo vague con total libertad". Pero esto es totalmente discutible, lo ofrezco como posibilidad.

Y la segunda frase

> ¿Quién gasta su opilación / Con oro y no con acero? / El Dinero

parece referirse a una costumbre de moda en el siglo de oro, que era comer "[búcaros](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%BAcaro)" (vasijas de barro) generando una obstrucción intestinal llamada "opilación", a la que se atribuían propiedades anticonceptivas y un aspecto anémico bastante prestigioso. Para curar la opilación se usaban polvos de hierro o beber unas aguas de "la fuente del Acero". Por cierto, el verbo "gastar" antes también significaba "digerir".

Entonces yo la interpreto así: "El dinero te permite obtener prestigio y otras bondades sin necesidad de complicados tratamientos". También es solo una proposición de mi parte.

Comment: Buena interpretacion se nota que eres una persona bien documentada.lo de la opilacion me parece brillante yo pensaba que en vez de hierro comían oro.